# Exception when i send my form Spring MVC

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, controller

I want to insert a record to database so this is my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ajouter_activite",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String AddActivity(@ModelAttribute Movement movement, ModelMap model,BindingResult result){
        AddActivityValidator actvalidator = new AddActivityValidator();
        actvalidator.validate(movement, result);
        if(!result.hasErrors()){
        boolean n;
        n=actservice.addMovement(movement);
        if(n==true){model.addAttribute("success","true");}
        else {model.addAttribute("echec","true");}
        return "/FicheService";}
        else{return "/FicheService";
        }

    }
```

When i send my form i get this exception :

```
Etat HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public java.lang.String gestion.delegation.controller.FicheServiceController.AddActivity(gestion.delegation.domaine.Movement,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model attribute. Check your handler method signature!
```

Where is the wrong with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
public String AddActivity(@ModelAttribute Movement movement, BindingResult result, ModelMap model)
```

method signature.

see example 17.1 in http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods for more info.

Comment: I just get it! Thank you! I must always put the model attribute first, then BindingResult and finally the model. the order is important.